# Is it bad-practice using left-handed coordinate system in OpenGL eye-space?

Tags: opengl, coordinates, projection

In the engine I am currently programming I want to use a left-handed coordinate system for eye-space instead of the glFrustum standard right-handed one. Is that in anyway considered bad practice?

Comment: The typical projection matrix will flip the Z-axis and you will have a a right-handed coordinate space if you do this. But there is nothing wrong with it *per-se*, you just have to understand that polygon winding and other things will be backwards unless you also adjust your clip-space, NDC, window space coordinate systems using the projection matrix.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's fine, you may use whatever coordinate system and handedness you prefer.

Just be aware of what you are doing so you can make the appropriate adjustments and assumptions.